# Jquery: How to make the content showup below the navigation bar when the anchor link is clicked?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

I have a fixed navigation on the top, when i click the anchor links to take me to a section in the page, i want it show in the visible space.

How can I make the content show up below the navigation(not behind)  , when the user click on the navigationlink to go to a specific section in a page?

I am open to using jquery with css

The demo can be viewed here in the jsfiddle

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dev1212/8yMN7/18/)

CODE

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="branding">
    <h1>Branding</h1>
    <ul id="mainNav"> 
    <li class="first"><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#link1">link1</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#link2">link2</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#link3">link3</a></li> 

    </ul> 

    </div> 

    <div id="content"> 



        <div id="form-b">

        <form id="comments_form" action="#" method="post">

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Your Contact Details  Link1 <a name="link1"></a> </legend>

      <p>
      <label for="author">Name: <span class="required">(Required)</span></label>
      <input name="author" id="author" type="text" />
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="feedback">Incorrect email address. Please try again.</span></label>
      <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="url">Web Address:</label>
      <input name="url" id="url" type="text" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>


    <fieldset>
      <legend>Your Contact Details  Link 2<a name="link2"></a> </legend>
      <p>
      <label for="author">Name: <span class="required">(Required)</span></label>
      <input name="author" id="author" type="text" />
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="feedback">Incorrect email address. Please try again.</span></label>
      <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="url">Web Address:</label>
      <input name="url" id="url" type="text" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Your Contact Details  Link 3<a name="link3"></a></legend>
      <p>
      <label for="author">Name: <span class="required">(Required)</span></label>
      <input name="author" id="author" type="text" />
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="feedback">Incorrect email address. Please try again.</span></label>
      <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="url">Web Address:</label>
      <input name="url" id="url" type="text" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Your Contact Details  </legend>
      <p>
      <label for="author">Name: <span class="required">(Required)</span></label>
      <input name="author" id="author" type="text" />
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="feedback">Incorrect email address. Please try again.</span></label>
      <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="url">Web Address:</label>
      <input name="url" id="url" type="text" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="submit-b">
      <legend>  </legend>
    <div class="wrap">  
      <p>
    <input id="submit" class="submit" name="submit" type="submit"/>
    </p>
    </div>
    </fieldset>

    </form>


        </div>

    </div> 



    <div id="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
    </div>


    </div>
```

CSS

```
<!--

/* Pretty Stuff
================================== */

/* Zero down margin and paddin on all elements */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font: 92.5%/1.6 "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, sans-serif;

}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.4em;
  font-weight: normal;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.0em;
  font-weight: normal;
}

p, li {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

h1, h2, p {
  margin: 1em 0;
}

#branding h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#branding {
   width:100%;  
}
#branding {

  background-color:#b0b0b0;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 0 ;

  /** for fixed postion **/
          position:fixed;
         z-index:99998;
             /*Making sure it sticks to left of window in IE7*/
              left:0;
             /*Change to reflect height of your header.
             Remember to accomadate for padding!*/
             height:100px;
}

#form-b {
 /* height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 164px;
    width: 98%;
*/
  margin-top:150px;
}
#mainNav {
  list-style: none;
  background-color:#eee;
}

#footer {
  background-color:#b0b0b0;
  padding: 1px 20px;
}

/* The Core Technique
================================= */

body {
  text-align: center; 
  min-width: 1260px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  text-align: left; 
}


#content { 
  width: 100%;
  float: right; 
}

#mainNav li{ 
/*  width: 180px; 
  float: left;  */
  display:inline;

} 
#submit-b {
   /* border: 0px solid red;
    bottom: 77px;

    position: fixed;
    text-align: cemter;
    width: 100%;
 */
 width:100%;
        float:left;
}
#submit-b {
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0;
        z-index:999999;
    }
.wrap {
        position:relative;
        margin:0 auto;
               /*replace 900px with your width*/
        width:900px;
    }

#footer { 
  clear: both; 
} 

/* Add some padding 
================================== */

#mainNav {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
   position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

#mainNav * {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#mainNav * * {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

#content * {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#content * * {
  padding-right: 0;
}

-->



/* fieldset styling */
fieldset {
  margin: 1em 0 0 0; /*  space out the fieldsets a little*/
  padding: 1em;
  border : 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color:#F5F5F5
}

/* legend styling */
legend {
  font-weight: bold;
}

form p {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

/* style for  labels */
label {
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
}

#remember-me label {
  width: 4em;
}

/* style for required labels */
label .required {
  font-size: 0.83em;
  color:#760000;
}

/* style error messages */
label .feedback {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 11em;
  left: 200px;
  right: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#760000;
  padding-left: 18px;
  background: url(images/error.png) no-repeat left top;
}

/* :KLUDGE: Explicitly set the width for IE6- */
* html .feedback{
  width: 10em;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
}

input[type="text"], textarea {
  border-top: 2px solid #999;
  border-left: 2px solid #999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input.radio, input.checkbox, input.submit {
  width: auto;
}

/* style form elements on focus */
input:focus, textarea:focus {
  background: #ffc;
}

input.radio {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

/* Date of Birth form styling */

#monthOfBirthLabel, #yearOfBirthLabel {
  text-indent: -1000em;
  width: 0;
}

#dateOfBirth {
  width: 3em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

#monthOfBirth {
  width: 10em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

#yearOfBirth {
  width: 5em;
}

/* Color form styling */
#favoriteColor {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}

#favoriteColor h2 {
  width: 10em;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#favoriteColor div {
  width: 8em;
  float: left;
}

#favoriteColor label {
  /*width: 3em;*/
  float: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do this with the set up as it exists. A fixed element will act as a screen over the viewport on all modern browsers.

As I see it, you've got two options:

1) Wire up some jQuery like this:

```
`$('div#branding ul li a').click (function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var location = $($(this).attr('href')).offsetParent();
    $('div.content').scrollTop(location.top);
});`
```

If you're going to go this route, I highly recommend adding the id to the anchor supplement with the same value as the name. If that's not possible, you'll need to change the selector in that code block to

`$('s[name=' + $(this).attr('href').substr(1) + ']')`

2) Change your fixed header to an absolute header, absolutely position div.content immediately below it, and set overflow-y to 'auto' on doc.content

**EDIT**

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/8yMN7/50/)

And here's the javascript I added.  This relies on you adding an ID to those links that matches their current `name` attribute:

```
$('ul#mainNav li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).attr('href') !== '#'){
        var location = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 150; /* For your header height, subtract 150 or whatever it ends up being */
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: location}, 600);
    } else {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600);
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you show me an example on how i could the jjuery on the DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/dev1212/8yMN7/49/ to implment it? Regarding option #2) I had tried that with overflow , i ran into lots of cross browser problem.

Comment: @user244394 I've updated my answer with a working fiddle and the jQuery needed to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that links to anchors automatically scroll the page until that anchor is at the top of the window. Combining sticky nav with anchor-based links isn't a good idea for this reason, but you could make it work by moving the anchors in the HTML and perhaps adjusting some of the CSS. So, for example, if you put the anchor for link2 somewhere inside the first fieldset you could get it to line up properly, but it's not a clean practice.